# peek value at specific queue index, dequeue, and enqueue, all 3 in constant time

Tags: arrays, queue, peek

I need to implement a queue, ideally in Java. It must implement the methods `void push(int value)`, `int pop()`, and `int peek(int index)`, all in constant time.

Note for push(), we input a value, whereas for peek() we input an index.

I've managed to implement push, pop, and peek in constant time by using a circular array. for pop i return head. for push, I put in after tail. For peek, I just return element in the array that's at the index passed.

My problem: if the array is not of fixed size, how do you push a new element in constant time while still keeping other 2 fxns constant? you have to increase the size of the array. so how do you do it?

I have 2 questions written as comments in the code; please do answer both, as well as provide code review!

please also help me resolve this comment in my code below:     /*one way I can think to find 'if (index not between head and tail)' is by looping circularly from head to tail and ensuring that index appears. to determine in constant time, 1 idea is to add all indicies in arr to a set as you go. any other constant time ideas?*/

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue q = new Queue();
  }

  public static class Queue<Integer> {

    //capacity == arr.length 
    private int capacity;
    private int head;
    private int tail;
    private int[] arr;
    private int size;

    public Queue () {
      capacity = 16;
      head = tail = 0; 
      arr = new int[capacity]; //0-15
      size = 0;
    }

    public void push(int value) {
      tail = (tail + 1) % capacity;

      //alternatively can look to use 'if (size == capacity)'
      if (tail == head) { 
        resize(); //not constant time when we're @ capacity; help!!
      }
      arr[tail] = i;
      size++;
    }

    private void resize() {
      int[] temp = new int[2 * capacity];
      int index = head;

      //arr.length == capacity
      for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[index];
        index = (index + 1) % capacity;
      }
      arr = temp;
      head = 0;
      tail = capacity + 1;
      this.capacity = capacity * 2;
    }


    public int pop() throws Exception{
      if (size == 0) {
        throw new EmptyQueueException();
      }
      int oldHead = head;
      head = (head + 1) % capacity; 
      size--;
      return oldHead; 
    }

    public int peek(int index) {
    /*one way I can think to find 'if (index not between head and tail)' is by looping circularly from head to tail and ensuring that index appears. to determine in constant time, 1 idea is to add all indicies in arr to a set as you go. any other constant time ideas?*/
    if (index not between head and tail) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return arr[index];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need *worst-case* constant time, or *amortized* constant time?

Comment: ideas: 1. each array element is an array or linkedlist rather than single int; when original array is filled, move on to 2nd layer. 2. create 2nd array when first is filled. however for both of these ideas, the time to update when elements are removed would be more than constant.

Comment: the code i provided is already amortized constant time ya? but im not sure if that's satisfactory or if i need worst case. i cant even see how worst case would be possible. i was also thinking requirement might be amortized, in which case i answered part 1 of my own q. unless anyone has idea for worst case.